# Multi-level database retrieval in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three Rails models and associations:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bills
  belongs_to :user
end

class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts
end
```

I am trying to create an endpoint that returns all users and their accounts and all the bills for the accounts.

Right now I am able to get all bills and their account through:

```
bill_records = Bill.all.includes(:account)
bill_records_with_associations = bill_records.map do |record|
  record.attributes.merge(
  'account' => record.account,
  )
```

but now I need to get the Users that are associated with each Account and I am at a loss.

Is it possible for me to retrieve the Users here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted solution works well. However, You might want to take advantage of eager loading and caching associated `User` objects of your `Account` objects with this ORM query:

```
bill_records = Bill.includes(:account => :user)
```

This will cache all the `User` objects associated with the queried `Account` objects. Then, the following code block just uses the cached result from the above query cutting down additional ORM queries to your db (`bill_records = Bill.includes(:account)` just caches the `Account` objects and makes ORM query on each `record.account.user` statement used below).

```
bill_records_with_associations = bill_records.map do |record|
  record.attributes.merge(
    'account' => record.account,
    'user' => record.account.user
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it...

```
bill_records = Bill.all.includes(:account)
bill_records_with_associations = bill_records.map do |record|
  record.attributes.merge(
  'account' => record.account,
  'user' => record.account.user
  )
end
```